# Canvas on mobile returns wrong colors

Tags: javascript, canvas

Im loading an image with 3 colors into a HTMLCanvas element on a mobile android device (Samsung Galaxy S3). When checking the used colors in the used imageData, I get a lot more colors. When running the same code on a usual PC, I get the exact colors and count.

Example code:

```
function getColorsFromImageData (imageData) { 
    var colors = {};
    var data = imageData.data;

    for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i += 4) {
        if (data[i+3] == 0) continue;
        var rgb = data[i] + "," + data[i+1] + "," + data[i+2];
        if (colors[rgb])
            colors[rgb]++;
        else
            colors[rgb] = 1;
    }
    return colors;
};

function createColorElement (color, count) {
    var elm = document.createElement("span");
    elm.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + color + ")";
    elm.className = "color";
    elm.innerHTML = color + " (" + count + ")";
    document.getElementById("colors").appendChild(elm);
}

window.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);

        var data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
        var colors = getColorsFromImageData(data);

        var count = 0;
        for (var color in colors) {
            createColorElement(color, colors[color]);
            count++;
        }

        document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = count;
    }
    img.src = "test.png";
};
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d6714wdg/

How can I get the exact colors on mobile?

Background: I create an online designer based on HTMLCanvas. I need exact color values and no anti aliasing because all colors need to fit in a set of predefined colors matching the used wool color.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: @Kaiido. Thanks for your help. I've found that answer as well and IMO this is a different issue as I use only pixel data with full opacity (alpha channel is 255) and my issue never happened on desktop implementations so far but only on mobile devices. Both Firefox and Chrome on mobile show the same behaviour.

Comment: Loading the jsfiddle in Chrome 43 on my mobile returns a total count of 15 colors (only 3 are originally defined). Maybe I don't fully understand the issue described in your linked explanation, but when looking at the color values in my jsfiddle they are all very close together and the ones I expect to see are present as well and the ones with the highest count. That doesn't fit to the explanation. Right? Thanks for sticking on the topic, I really appreciate it.

Comment: My bad, that wasn't the problem at all. And it actually does fix my own issue so thank you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're facing is due to the canvas doing smoothing on `drawImage()` by default.

This can be turned off by setting the context's [`imageSmoothingEnabled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/imageSmoothingEnabled) property to `false`.

This property is not yet stabilized and you'll need constructor prefixes :

```
 ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
 ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
 ctx.msImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
 ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
 ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
```

[**updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/d6714wdg/4/)

Comment: Oh my god! I used to disable imageSmoothing all the time but didn't expected different behaviour on mobile. Now everything is cool again. You rocked my day. Thanks a lot!